# Insert Cart::content() into multiple Row From View Using Eloquent Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, shopping-cart, cart

How can I insert Multiple Row of Cart:: content() in Laravel 5.
I'm using Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart for my cart, however, when you click on proceed to payment, I want the user to fill Customer details like (Terminal ID, sale date, and customer name. But I'm having issue with inserting Cart::(Content) into my database (I dont want to insert instance. I like to break the cart down to my database column. example, if someone pick like 2-5 items, I want it to be inserted to my db, with each item in each row. I've break the Cart::content down in my view, but I need to be able to use Laravel to insert multiple row based on the number of Items selected. 
**PLEASE NOTE: IF I ONLY ADD ONLY ONE ITEM TO CART, I'M ABLE TO INSERT TO DATABASE, IT'S ONLY WHEN THE ITEM IN CART IS MORE THAN ONE THAT I HAVE ISSUE WITH.** 
Below is my proceed.blade.php

```
 <div class="panel-heading">Customer Detail</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
       @if (sizeof(Cart::content()) > 0)
    {!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> 'SalesController@store','files'=>true]) !!}
       {!! Form::text('counter', $counter=Cart::content()->groupBy('id')->count(),  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
        @foreach (Cart::content() as $item)
        <div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('product_name', 'Product Name:') !!}
  {!! Form::text('product_name', $item->name,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}                     </div>
          <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('quantity', 'Quantity:') !!}
  {!! Form::text('quantity', $item->qty,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
         </div>
       <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('unit_price', 'Unit Price:') !!}
  {!! Form::text('unit_price', $item->price,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                     </div>
       <div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::label('rowId', 'Row ID:') !!}
   {!! Form::text('rowId', $item->rowId,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
       </div>
    <div class="form-group">
           {!! Form::label('tax', 'Tax:') !!}
        {!! Form::text('tax', $item->tax,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
           </div>
            <div class="form-group">
      {!! Form::label('total_price', 'Sub Total:') !!}
      {!! Form::text('total_price', $item->subtotal,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
           </div>
          @endforeach

                     @endif
         <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('terminal_id', 'Terminal ID:') !!}
       {!! Form::text('terminal_id', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group">
       {!! Form::label('customer_name', 'Customer Name:') !!}
   {!! Form::text('customer_name', null,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                        </div>
                      <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::label('sale_date', 'Sale Date:') !!}
         {!! Form::text('sale_date', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
          {!! Form::submit('Check Out', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
                       </div>
         {!! Form::close() !!}
`
```

MY CONTROLLER

```
$counter= $request['counter'];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($counter); $i++) {
Sale::create([
             'terminal_id' => $request['terminal_id'],
             'customer_name' => $request['customer_name'],
             'unit_price' => $request['unit_price'],
             'total_price' => $request['total_price'],
             'tax' => $request['tax'],
             'quantity' => $request['quantity'],
             'product_name' => $request['product_name'],
             'sale_date' => $request['sale_date'],
             'rowId' => $request['rowId']
    ]);

    }
    return redirect('shop');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your fields are not arrays so with each `@foreach` in your view, the old value overrides.

Make your inputs to Array inputs by changing your view this way:

```
<div class="panel-heading">Customer Detail</div>
<div class="panel-body">
@if (sizeof(Cart::content()) > 0)
{!! Form::open(['method'=>'POST', 'action'=> 'SalesController@store','files'=>true]) !!}
{!! Form::text('counter', $counter=Cart::content()->groupBy('id')->count(),  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
<?php $idx = 0; ?>
@foreach (Cart::content() as $item)
  <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label("product_name[$idx]", 'Product Name:') !!}
  {!! Form::text("product_name[$idx]", $item->name,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label("quantity[$idx]", 'Quantity:') !!}
  {!! Form::text("quantity[$idx]", $item->qty,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label("unit_price[idx]", 'Unit Price:') !!}
  {!! Form::text("unit_price[idx]", $item->price,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label("rowId[$idx]", 'Row ID:') !!}
  {!! Form::text("rowId[$idx]", $item->rowId,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label("tax[$idx]", 'Tax:') !!}
  {!! Form::text("tax[$idx]", $item->tax,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label("total_price[$idx]", 'Sub Total:') !!}
  {!! Form::text("total_price[$idx]", $item->subtotal,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
  </div>
  <?php $idx++; ?>
@endforeach
@endif
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('terminal_id', 'Terminal ID:') !!}
  {!! Form::text('terminal_id', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('customer_name', 'Customer Name:') !!}
  {!! Form::text('customer_name', null,  ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::label('sale_date', 'Sale Date:') !!}
  {!! Form::text('sale_date', null, ['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  {!! Form::submit('Check Out', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}
</div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

I suggest you also putting your `for` loop in a transaction in order to improve it's safety.

Like this:

```
public function store(SalesCreateRequest $request) {
  $counter = Input::get('counter');
  \DB::transaction(function() use ($counter){
    for ($i=0; $i < $counter; $i++){
      Sale::create([
        'terminal_id' => Input::get("terminal_id")[$i],
        'customer_name'=> Input::get("customer_name")[$i],
        'unit_price'=> Input::get("unit_price")[$i],
        'total_price'=> Input::get("total_price")[$i],
        'tax'=> Input::get("tax")[$i],
        'quantity'=> Input::get("quantity")[$i],
        'product_name'=> Input::get("product_name")[$i],
        'sale_date'=> Input::get("sale_date")[$i],
        'rowId'=> Input::get("rowId")[$i]
      ]);
    }
  });
  return "working";
}
```

**Note** that you could simply add a `[]` suffix instead of `[$idx]` in your input names to make your inputs arrays, but usually indexing your inputs explicitly is safer.

**Edit** the `$idx` key from `Cart::content()` was returning a weird number, that was why simple numerical numbers threw `Out of range exception`.

Change your view code as I did above, I hope fixing it this way.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks @ahmad, I'm getting ErrorException in `SalesController.php line 46: Undefined variable: counter.` .... I include  **$counter = Input::get('counter');** before the for-loop in the transaction. and I'm getting another Error `Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection as array`. Please help!

Comment: Probably by putting the for loop outside of `\DB:transaction` block, the problem should disappear. If you want to keep the transaction block, you need to add `use ($counter, $request)` to the transaction's closure as I did in the answer above.

Comment: @Thanks Ahmad, I've tried what you send I got **Undefined variable: counter**, so I put for-loop outside the transactions, but I'm getting another error **Undefined variable: i**. I added `$counter = Input::get('counter');` before \DB::transaction. but still getting error `Integrity constraint violation: 1048` ('insert into `sales` (`terminal_id`, `customer_name`, `unit_price`, `total_price`, `tax`, `quantity`, `product_name`, `sale_date`, `rowId`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,))

Comment: can you put your controller's code? Probably there's a variable conflict there.

Comment: `public function store(SalesCreateRequest $request)
{ $counter = Input::get('counter');
\DB::transaction(function() use ($counter, $request){
for ($i=0; $i < count($counter); $i++){
Sale::create([ 'terminal_id' =>$request["terminal_id[$i]"],
'customer_name'=>$request["customer_name[$i]"],
'unit_price'=>$request["unit_price[$i]"],
'total_price'=>$request["total_price[$i]"],
'tax'=>$request["tax[$i]"],
'quantity'=>$request["quantity[$i]"],
'product_name'=>$request["product_name[$i]"],
'sale_date'=>$request["sale_date[$i]"],
'rowId'=>$request["rowId[$i]"] ]);
}}); return "working";}`

Comment: **@Ahmad**.... Sorry for the way the code was posted, can post more than 600 character! Thanks in Anticipation!

Comment: Seems the array index in request is accessible out of it's key. I edited my answer according to your controller's code. Let me know if the problem is solved this way

Comment: Getting::ErrorException in SalesController.php line 49:
Undefined offset: 0
in SalesController.php line 49
at HandleExceptions->handleError(8, 'Undefined offset: 0', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\lara\\employee\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\SalesController.php', 49, array('counter' => '1', 'request' => object(SalesCreateRequest), 'i' => 0)) in SalesController.php line 49.:: My Line 49 is :  `'unit_price'=>$request["unit_price"][$i],`

Comment: seems the `$request` object modifies the input, I changed the code to use `Input::get` instead of `$request`

Comment: You're sure the view is written as above? maybe your `unit_price` input is not an array yet!

Comment: Sir, I dont think the issue is with `unit_price` because after comment it out, still getting same error.  As per your question  
`You're sure the view is written as above?` .... YES!!...... I'm very sorry for disturbing you.....  Please help!

Comment: I guess you need debugging your input data to make sure everything is posted correctly. try adding `return '<pre>'.print_r(Input::all(), true).'</pre>'` in the first line of your `store` method to check if your input data is a correct array without data loss.

Comment: kindly find the screenshot of the array when I use print the reqyest input. The first shop is when I add just one Items to the cart and the second is when I added two item to cart.  [OneItem ScreenShot](http://test.nazarethhost.com/OneItem.png) and [TwoItem ScreenShot](http://test.nazarethhost.com/TwoItems.png). I'm seeing array inside array... Hope you can help figure the error out. Thank sir

Comment: Wow!! just found the problem, the $idx variable in view is that weird key in your debug data! I'll change my answer to make it working.

Comment: ,.... I noticed that its only array [0] that is insert to my db.  Kindly find print all output on [Array of Two Items](http://test.nazarethhost.com/ArrayTwoItems.png) and my database [database view](http://test.nazarethhost.com/dbforItems.png). Thanks for your help thus far.

Comment: You're right. that's because `$counter` is not an array so counting it doesn't make sense. I changed the controller's method to correct this part. hope it solves the problem.

Comment: Whao..... It works!!! Thanks so much. please can you advice your email address? I like to mail you. Thanks BIG!!!

Comment: Great. Glad it worked finally. my email address is accessible in my profile.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your controller

```
$counter = $request['counter'];
\DB::transaction(function() use ($counter, $request) {
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($counter); $i++) {
   Sale::create([
   'terminal_id' => $request["terminal_id"],
   'customer_name' => $request["customer_name"],
   'unit_price' => $request["unit_price"][$i],
   'total_price' => $request["total_price"][$i],
   'tax' => $request["tax"][$i],
   'quantity' => $request["quantity"][$i],
   'product_name' => $request["product_name"][$i],
   'sale_date' => $request["sale_date"],
   'rowId' => $request["rowId"][$i]
  ]);
 }
});
```

**NOTE**

Not all input fields are array (terminal_id, sale_date...)

Comment: Still getting Error::SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'terminal_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `sales` (`terminal_id`, `customer_name`, `unit_price`, `total_price`, `tax`, `quantity`, `product_name`, `sale_date`, `rowId`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (, , , , , , , , , 2017-06-28 19:08:54, 2017-06-28 19:08:54)).

Comment: in Connection.php line 647
at Connection->runQueryCallback('insert into `sales` (`terminal_id`, `customer_name`, `unit_price`, `total_price`, `tax`, `discount`, `quantity`, `product_name`, `sale_date`, `rowId`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', array(null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, '2017-06-28 19:08:54', '2017-06-28 19:08:54'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 607

Comment: Getting error:: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'unit_price' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `sales` (`terminal_id`, `customer_name`, `unit_price`, `total_price`, `tax`, `discount`, `quantity`, `product_name`, `sale_date`, `rowId`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (10330101, BAUHLARE, , , , , , , 2010-10-10, , 2017-06-28 20:05:18, 2017-06-28 20:05:18)). HOWEVER, IN MY VIEW TEXT, THE UNIT_PRICE and other text-field are not null but in the error, its showing null.

Comment: I need to see your controller and view files. You can share on github or any suitable means.